# YouTube API: The request metadata specifies an invalid video description

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have trouble with the videos.insert method when I set the description.

```
$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle(strip_tags($webinar['subject']));
// Prepare description
$description = preg_replace('/ {2,}/',' ',$webinar['description']);
// $description = strip_tags($description);
$snippet->setDescription($description);
```

Return Error:

> A service error occurred: Error calling PUT
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UpePMcweB9uaZoO_Vm8sH8DnVuDb1pU-rgZYfnTmYPMJlLLaDN7oLDz184UKtcX4j5eecDzHtxT1XJws2v-p9aeJTDkq874DZOXSEaLYKqyUfhqUds:
>   (400) Failed to parse Content-Range header.

I got this description from the DB with an html-like tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload one youtube video on another youtube channel with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349366/how-to-upload-one-youtube-video-on-another-youtube-channel-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Problam in path to video file. It was wrong, so it make some problem in header.